# Delete redux state on navigating to a different route in react-redux application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, flux

I am writing a react-redux application, that has some 4 routes. I am using react-router to navigate to different routes. My question here is, is it recommended to delete redux state on navigating to a different route?

Comment: I would assume that Redux represents _all_ of your application state which would include all the different routes. So no, don't delete the state. That makes no sense.

Comment: Yes redux state stores all the data for all the routes. I was thinking of removing only that part of an application state which is required by the route which I am not in currently.

Comment: And considering the fact that I load data by calling API server on componentDidMount life cycle method, hence I am not sure even if I don't delete redux state of that route how is that going to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general I would not say it is needed to delete existing state when transitioning to another route in the app. If you come back to that part, you can display data faster. You might need to consider if there is a need to refresh that when you come back to it.

Comment: Since I load data by calling API server on componentDidMount life cycle method, hence I am not sure even I dont delete redux state how is that going to help me?

Comment: you could skip the call if the data is already there, if that fits your use case

Comment: Yes that make sense. Thanks bro :)

Answer (score 1):

As other's here said, there is no reason to delete state from redux, even if you're not using it in the current route.

You said that you're loading your state on `componentDidMount`. Do you want to reload server data every time a route is switched? Because if not, you can add a condition to your `componentDidMount` to only re-load the data from the server if it hasn't been loaded yet.

Comment: Actually I don't want to reload data from server everytime a route is switched because I have a automatic refresh  enabled on routes which will ensure to get fresh updated data from server. The only trick will be to know the time lapsed from last un-mounting, so that I can query for any change happened during interval (unmounting to remounting) from server.

Comment: Just a suggestion. Create an unmountedTimestamps reducer and on ```componentWillUnmount``` dispatch an actions with the route name and the current timestamp

Comment: Thats cool suggestion, love you bro :) love stackoverflow (y)